# OrientDB SQL: is it possible to limit edge path via multiple edge properties?

Tags: sql, orientdb

I have a query, using the edge path filtering over the `type` property:

```
select *, outE('HAS_CONTENT')[type='D'].inV()[0].`name` as `content-name` from Root ORDER BY `content-name` desc limit 5
```

It works, but is not fulfilling the needs, as I want the sortable field `name` being fetched more precisely over multiple edge property limitations, namely `type` and `language`, producing zero results if no edges match all the restrictions. Unfortunately, neither of the following is supported by the OrientDB SQL syntax:

```
select *, outE('HAS_CONTENT')[type='D' && language = 'EN'].inV()[0].`name` as `content-name` from Root ORDER BY `content-name` desc limit 5
select *, outE('HAS_CONTENT')[type='D', language = 'EN'].inV()[0].`name` as `content-name` from Root ORDER BY `content-name` desc limit 5
```

The following is syntactically accepted, but does not seem to match the data structure, producing erratic results:

```
select *, outE('HAS_CONTENT')[type='D'][language = 'EN'].inV()[0].`name` as `content-name` from Root ORDER BY `content-name` desc limit 5
```

Is it possible to limit the edge path via multiple edge property filters at once, with current OrientDB SQL syntax?

Comment: Which version of OrientDB are you using, the syntax you are using will not work in 3.x refer https://orientdb.com/docs/last/sql/SQL-Match.html refer section TRAVERSE Alternative

Comment: It does work in 3.2.10. At least it throws no error and produces the correct results.